Shopify Remix Template: "Oauth error failed_grant_with_invalid_scopes" and Localhost 404 Issue
I am trying to create a Shopify app using the Remix template provided by Shopify. I followed all the instructions in their documentation. While I have good experience in Shopify app development using PHP and Laravel (with custom setups), I am new to Remix and facing an issue that I haven’t encountered before.
Previously, I successfully built Shopify apps using Laravel and Express templates without any issues. However, with the Remix template, I am running into the following problems:

After running the command:
shopify add dev



The link provided by the CLI to access the app gives me a 404 Page Not Found error.

it will show the error like 404 page not found then I tried with they generated local URL like

When I use the generated local URL (e.g., http://localhost:57632/) and input my development store URL as prompted, I get the following error:
Oauth error failed_grant_with_invalid_scopes: The application could not be installed 
due to invalid scopes requested.



[
in the env file I have scopes like this
SCOPES="write_products, read_products, read_themes,write_themes"

